# Commit/Rollback SQL Transaction in Asynchronous Process

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, asynchronous, commit, rollback

Is it possible to commit and rollback transaction in an asynchronous process?

I am using Vb.Net and SQL Server. My code is:

```
 If connString.ToString.ToUpper.Contains("ASYNCHRONOUS PROCESSING=TRUE") = False Then
        connString = connString & ";Asynchronous Processing=True;"
    End If
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        cn.Open()
        Dim tr As SqlTransaction = cn.BeginTransaction()
        Using tr
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
                cmd.Transaction = tr
                Try
                    Dim count As Integer = 0
                    Dim result As IAsyncResult = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery()
                    While Not result.IsCompleted

                        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                        count += 1
                    End While


                Catch ex As Exception

                    tr.Rollback()
                    lSuccess = False
                    ErrMsg = ex.ToString


                    GoTo skip
                End Try
            End Using

            tr.Commit()

        End Using
skip:       If Not cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Close()

    End Using
End If
```

If the transaction is successfully done, it produces error in `tr.Rollback` line saying that SQLTransaction is completed and no longer usable.

Kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the second tr.Commit just after the End Using for the SqlCommand?

Comment: And you don't need also to test for ConnectionState. Exiting the Using block will close/dispose the connection

Comment: @Steve , I have deleted the first tr.Commit.

Comment: your code does not makes sense. If an exception occurs you do a rollback and later you still do a commit. Put the commit as last line in the try just before the catch ex as exception so you do commit or rollback, not both

Comment: @GuidoG, I have deleted the first tr.Commit. And, tr.Rollback is needed if execution is failed due to network related error.

Comment: No @angel you should delete the last commit and leave the first. And please do not change the original code. Otherwise this discussion seems to be totally wrong

Comment: I don't know vb but the commit looked better where it was to me. I would keep it in the try block

Comment: I agree with Steve, it is hard to comment when the code keeps changing

Comment: @Steve, apologize.

Comment: @Steve, it produces same error even if I place tr.Commit before the "catch ex . . " line

Comment: if the commit is at that place, the rollback should not be executed. So what is exact your problem and error ? On what line does the error happens ?

Comment: Please [see this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) on how to use correctly BeginExecuteNonQuery. In your code there is no EndExecuteNonQuery